# Prevent picking past date on datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have used datepicker to let users choose a day but I do not want to let users choose the date has already passed. I also found I can use `minDate: new Date()` but when I added this, the first time the page loads it runs normally, however when I reload the page, it breaks. I applied this for asp.net page

[image]

and this is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    $('.date').daterangepicker({
               timePicker: true,
               timePickerIncrement: 30,
               minDate: new Date ,
               locale: {
               format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
               }
            });
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: should'nt minDate be set to date constructor? minDate: new Date(),